# Как использовать пользовательские события (CustomEvent) в не DOM объектах?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо использовать собственные события в JS. Я хочу создать функцию и определить для неё `prototype`. В нём создается событие и делается `dispatchEvent`. На это событие можно подписаться извне при помощи `addEventListener`. То есть я могу получить объект который способен генерировать свои события. В ряде случаев вместо этого можно использовать колбэк. Но события позволяют реализовать связь "один ко многим" вместо "один к одному" у колбэков и ослабить зависимости модулей друг от друга. Проблема в том, что такое возможно например для DOM элементов, в прототипе же пустого объекта конечно нет событийных функций.

Как реализовать такой функционал без использования сторонних фреймвёрков? Только полностью запрограммировать событийную модель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще делается вручную, особенно если отделить чистый JS от DOM API.
Вот пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15308371/custom-events-model-without-using-dom-events-in-javascript

Comment: Спасибо! Код будет исполняться в браузере. Есть ли смысл пытаться скопировать нужный функционал из прототипов DOM'a или лучше сразу делать руками?

Comment: Проще руками, кода то всего ничего.